# Does compiz use hardware acceleration by default?

Tags: compiz, gpu, effects, ccsm, hardware-acceleration

How do I find out if Compiz is using my graphics card?

If it's disabled how do I enable it?

Comment: What is your graphics card? Do you have the drivers for it?and use it for every day use? In this case of course compiz will use hardware acceleration if it is available for it.

Comment: @markkirby yes of course. Nvidia GTX770 using nvidia 352.63 drivers

Comment: With that card you can use the compiz settings manger to configure compiz to your liking, it will have hardware acceleration by default with the nvidia driver, this program will let you set up compiz as you see fit, including animation and effects and that kind of thing `sudo apt-get installcompizconfig-settings-manager`

Comment: okay so I guess it *is* hardware accelerated by default. thanks